# javascript pass var to php

Tags: javascript

would it be possible to pass the contents of var `reason` to action=report?

```
function redirectConfirm(url)
{

var msg = "Are you sure?";
var reason = prompt("Reason");

if (confirm(msg))
{
    location.href=url;
}
}
```

And link

```
<a onClick="javascript:redirectConfirm('thread.php?id=$id&action=report');">Report post</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as query string:

```
location.href=url + '&reason='  + reason;
```

Later in PHP, you can get it through `$_GET`:

```
$_GET['reason'];
```

Comment: ... but if it solved your problem, please mark the answwer as *Accepted*.